# Can I make a system restore point by date?

Tags: windows-7, system-restore

Can I make System restore point before a particular date? For example, I want restore my PC by two months before. if it can how to do it?

PC specs: Win 7 64bit SP-1

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can always create a restore point before a particular date but not in your past.

However you can restore your computer two months back provided the system restore point exists.

Please refer to [this](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/restore-system-files-and-settings)

Comment: The furthest restore point my PC made was 19th of this month.  when I checked setting only 5% of my hard drive was reserved for restoring. Now I have maximized it to 20%.

Comment: @rayanA how on earth do you think it's even possible in any way to restore your computer to a backup that wasn't made.  That is absolutely ridiculous.  You need to start giving some thought to how things  work and how they could work.

Answer (score 0):

System restore points in Windows can be made manually using the following steps:
(upto win 7)**Go to start button->then on the Computer option do the right click and go tho the properties and click it.After that a new page opens and then click the system protection.After this you will reach a small page where there a Configure option and Create option.The Create option can be used to create manually new System Restore Points and you can name that point as you like.Whenever you install new programs and occasionally Windows create it's own restore points.When these new restore points are created the old Restore points gets deleted.So be careful about that.

Comment: I performed  Ccleaners registry scan then I deleted all results[ roughly 2 months ago]. I didn't made a backup [ backup prompt appeared but I ignored it]...  I am a novice .... my  IE browser now never load a youtube video I have previously watched , few videos load when I refresh the page 3 to 4 times. so i want make a restore point previous to 2 months but the most previous restore point my pc made on 19th this month. I think this is probably because the space reserved for this was only 5% of harddrive.So what should i do? I mean how can i go back to 2 months

Comment: Now you have said it clearly that you are trying to create a restore point to a date two months old, the answer is "Its not possible".